# Why does streaming query with socket source and multiple sinks not work?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to use multiple queries to write to different sinks in spark. The first query works and the output is written to the sink, but the second one does not.

Could anybody point what is my mistake.

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
val source = spark.readStream
  .format("socket")
  .option("host", "localhost")
  .option("port", 9999)
  .load()
  .as[String]
  .map {e =>
    println(e)
    e
  }

// With Multiple Queries
val q1 = source.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1000))
  .start()
println(q1)

val q2 = source.writeStream.outputMode("append")
  .format("csv")
  .option("path", "output.csv")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint/test")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1000))
  .start()
println(q2)

spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

Console Sink is working but CSV sink is not writing the output. If I change the order then csv sink works but not console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you're using netcat, or similar utility to produce the data. Such utilities are not designed to be replayable and don't provide persistence layer, so as a result data is irreversibly destroyed once consumed.

Therefore the second stream will listen to changes, but no data will ever reach it.

Comment: streaming with kafka source and multiple writestreams possible ?